# Keras implementation: Custom loss function with uncertainty output

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network

For a regression task I'd like to customize the loss function to output a certainty measure additionally.

The initial normal network would be:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(15, input_dim=7, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Dense(1, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
```

I'd like to add a **certainty indicator** `sigma` to the loss function. E.g. depending on how accurate the predictions are different `sigma` sizes lead to minimal loss.

```
loss = (y_pred-y_true)^2/(2*sigma^2) + log(sigma)
```

The final outputs of the NN would then be `y_pred` and `sigma`.

I'm a bit lost in the implementation (new to keras):

1. Where would we initialize/store `sigma` for it to be updated around recurring, similar datapoints during training.
2. How do we connect the variable `sigma` from the loss function to the second NN output.

My current base stucture, where I'm obviously lacking the pieces

```py
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred, sigma):
    loss = pow((y_pred - y_true), 2)/(2 * pow(sigma, 2))+math.log(sigma)
    return loss, sigma

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(15, input_dim=7, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam')
```

Any tips/guidances are highly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to extend y_pred from a scalar to a vector

```
def custom_loss(y_true, y_pred):
    loss = pow((y_pred[0] - y_true), 2) / (2 * pow(y_pred[1], 2)) + \
           tf.math.log(y_pred[1])
    return loss

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(15, input_dim=7, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.add(Dense(2, kernel_initializer='normal'))
model.compile(loss=custom_loss, optimizer='adam')
```

The model then returns the sigma to the prediction.

```
Y = model.predict(X)  # Y = [prediction, sigma]
```